# r shiny live locally on a different path/domain

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

It is possible to run a shiny server in R via the command line.

```
> R -e "shiny::runApp('~/Development/shiny_folder')
```

This brings the shiny app alive on `http://127.0.0.1:3192`. I can customise this a little by bringing it live to another port via;

```
> R -e "shiny::runApp('~/Development/shiny_folder', port=9999)"
```

So far so good. But is it also possible to specify a path as well? The following code does not work.

```
> R -e "shiny::runApp('~/Development/shiny_folder', port=9999, host = getOption('shiny.host','127.0.0.1/foobar/'))"
```

It gives the following error:

```
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1/foobar/:9999
Error in startServer(host, port, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) :
  Failed to create server
Calls: <Anonymous> -> startApp -> startServer
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you're wanting your Shiny app to be displayed at `http://127.0.0.1/foobar`?

The Shiny package itself doesn't have that functionality, but there are a number of ways you could achieve this.

The simplest way is to use nginx as a reverse proxy--start Shiny on port 9999, and use something like this in your `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /foobar/ {
      rewrite ^/foobar/(.*)$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:9999/ $scheme://$host/foobar/;
    }
}
```

If you've got more than one app and/or plan to expose your apps on e.g. a intranet (or the internet), you probably want Shiny Server, which does exactly what you're doing here (routing URLs to Shiny apps) plus a lot more. There are open source and commercial versions:

http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/